# Puppeteer input not typing all characters

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have some trouble with typing multi lines characters into a wysiwyg input.

I use this code :

```
  await page.goto('https://someurl.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
  //This button display a popup when a click is done
  await page.waitForSelector('.sendBtn', {visible: true});
  await page.click('.sendBtn');
  //Wait for modal input field to appear
  await page.waitForSelector('.modal.input', {visible: true});
  const textInput = await page.$('.modal.input');
  await textInput.click();
  await textInput.focus();
  await textInput.type('Hello,');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.type('Some text ');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.type('Some text again');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.press('Enter');
  await textInput.type('Some text to the end');
```

It's working but the first characters of the text are always missing, sometimes one, sometimes 10 characters...
It's really annoying.
I tried to add focus(), click(), networkidle0 waiting but nothing work.

It seems that the problem is well known, but I don't understand why such an obvious and old problem is still relevant, and why it is always closed and why it's always closed before being reopened again, since 2017 ! :

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1648

Or maybe it is because the modal is not fully loaded ? Even if I waitFor the input field in modal to be visible ?

I added a : "await page.waitFor(500);"
It works, but it is uggly...

Comment: What site is this, in the interests of a [mcve]?

Comment: see this: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1648
It's an open issue in the github issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue still exist in 2022. there is hot discussion on topic [In this github issue](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1648) you can try different approaches & see which one works for you. None of them actually worked for me. Here is something I did & its working like charm.

```js
await page.$eval(
      "[name='j_idt31:verisysForm:issuedate_input']",
      (InputField, value) => (issueDateField.value = value),
      value
    );
```

Comment: this problem still exists in 2023 too!  Also, your code snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open github issue on this bug:https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1648

Meanwhile you can do the following workaround:

```
await this.page.waitFor(1000);
await this.page.waitForSelector("your selector", {visible: true, timeout: 60000});
await this.page.focus("your selector");
await this.page.type("your selector", text, {delay: 100});
```

this works for me although i use the deprecated function: waitFor(1000).

Comment: Still works in August of 2023. I couldn't find any other way to mitigate this issue.